# codeigniter - You have not selected a database type to connect to

Tags: php, codeigniter, database-connection

I am working on codeigniter. While connecting the database I got following error:

```
    $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'mypass';
$db['default']['database'] = 'mydatabase';
$db['default']['mysqli'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Error:`You have not selected a database type to connect to.`

I gone through SO and also google, but not getting proper solution. Codeigniter version is 2.1.2

I have selected the database as shown above

Comment: hi, if you are working with ci2.1.2, first  this arrar is wrong, because, below `$db['default']['mysqli'] = 'mysql';` must be $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';``

Comment: It worked. thanks.

Comment: Its time to update your CI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not initializing your DB driver in your file

Try this

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'dbName';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: I have the same error: You have not selected a database type to connect to.$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';

Comment: basically I was trying to connect to anotherDB dynamically, querying the database table from firstDB. and that was making problem. Now its ok. thanks